# PL/SQL stored procedure which outputs values depending on user input value

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have an Oracle table (sample):

```
+----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|     DEPT                   |   BUILDINGID   |      GEOMETRY         |
+----------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Emergency Services AMB     |      516       |  [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] |
| Emergency Services AMB     |      287       |  [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] |
| Emergency Services FIRE    |      283       |  [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] |
| Emergency Services FIRE    |      460       |  [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] |
| Emergency Services POLICE  |      515       |  [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] |
+----------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

I am making a PL/SQL stored procedure where the user is asked to insert a department they wish. Then the department name will be linked to its ID (BUILDINGID) and the LONGITUDE and LATITUDE.

The output needs to be as follows:

```
Type of Building:

BUILDINGID      LONGITUDE      LATITUDE
----------      ---------      --------
```

I have started the following code but I stuck on trying to link the `BUILDINGID` with the department that the user inputs. As well, how do I show the longitude and latitude separately? (Since they are found in `[MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]` )?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE outputBuilding              --create procedure
  (i_building_type IN VARCHAR2 (20),
   i_BuildingID IN OTTAWABUILDINGS.BUILDINGID%TYPE,
   i_longitude IN OTTAWABUILDINGS.GEOMETRY%Type,
   i_latitude IN OTTAWABUILDINGS.GEOMETRY%Type) IS


CURSOR c_building IS
SELECT DEPT, BUILDINGID
FROM OTTAWABUILDINGS;
r_building c_building%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
v_type := '&TypeOfBuilding';   --user inserts type of building

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Type of Building: ' ||v_type);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('BUILDINGID   ' || 'LONGITUDE   ' ||'LATITUDE    ' );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('----------   ' || '----------   ' ||'----------    ' );

    FOR r_building IN c_building
    LOOP 
        SELECT DEPT INTO v_type FROM OTTAWABUILDINGS WHERE DEPT = v_type;
        IF v_type = 'Emergency Services POLICE' OR
        v_type = 'Emergency Services AMB' OR
        v_type = 'Emergency Services FIRE' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (i_BuildingID || '   ' || i_longitude || '   ' || i_latitude);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END outputBuilding;

-----------TESTING STORED PROCEDURE---------------
BEGIN
  outputBuilding (i_BuildingID, i_longitude, i_latitude);
END;
```

Comment: This is not a stored procedure - just a sqlplus script.  There are methods on the MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY to get the attributes.  Read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objrelschema.htm#CBBDAFFA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Designing procedures requires a bit of planning and thought.  You need to understand the requirements and implement them in code.

So the first requirement is:

> the user is asked to insert a department they wish

This means your procedure should take a single parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE outputBuilding             
  (i_building_type IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
```

Note that parameters are not constrained by length (just as well, as 'Emergency Services POLICE' exceeds twenty characters).

Next requirement:

> the department name will be linked to

This means you need to use the parameter to filter your query.  For the sake of clarity we'll stick with your explicit cursor.

```
CURSOR c_building IS
    SELECT DEPT, BUILDINGID
    FROM OTTAWABUILDINGS
    where dept = i_building_type;
```

Next requirement is:

> the department name will be linked to its ID (BUILDINGID) and the LONGITUDE and LATITUDE

Hmmm, we'd better include the geometry column in the query.

```
CURSOR c_building IS
    SELECT DEPT, BUILDINGID, geometry
    FROM OTTAWABUILDINGS
    where dept = i_building_type;
r_building c_building%ROWTYPE;
```

Final, and stickiest,  requirement

> show the longitude and latitude separately

This rather depends on how the longitude and latitude are stored.  We should hope they are stored as Points.  So you need something like this:

```
v_long := r_building.geometry.SDO_POINT.X;
v_lat := r_building.geometry.SDO_POINT.Y;
```

Caveat: I don't have access to a database with spatial right now, so this is not guaranteed.

Redundancies in the code:

- don't mix SQL*Plus syntax with PL/SQL.  The user passes the Building Type through the parameter so remove this: `v_type := '&TypeOfBuilding';`
- likewise, you don't need the query in the loop, as the cursor selects the information you need.
- you are just selecting data, so there's no need for a `commit`.

So a revised stored procedure would look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE outputBuilding             
  (i_building_type IN VARCHAR2) 
IS

    CURSOR c_building IS
        SELECT DEPT, BUILDINGID, geometry
        FROM OTTAWABUILDINGS
        where dept = i_building_type;
    r_building c_building%ROWTYPE;

    v_long varchar2(28);
    v_lat varchar2(28);

BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Type of Building: ' ||v_type);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('BUILDINGID   ' || 'LONGITUDE    ' ||'LATITUDE    ' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('----------   ' || '----------   ' ||'----------    ' );

    FOR r_building IN c_building
    LOOP 
        v_long := r_building.geometry.SDO_POINT.X;
        v_lat := r_building.geometry.SDO_POINT.Y;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (r_building.BuildingID || '   ' || v_long || '   ' || v_lat);
    END LOOP;
END outputBuilding;
```

I'll repeat my statement about not having Spatial, so I can't compile this.  Hence,  it may contain syntax bugs, which are left as an exercise for the reader.

To call it:

```
begin
    outputBuilding('Emergency Services POLICE');
end;
```

Comment: thank you for the clarification of the procedure. I am new at PL SQL and sometimes I get it confused with SQL Script. Your code works.